# Mapping my data to a Zip Code area map in R

Tags: r, mapping, zipcode

My data is like this:

```
ZIPcode Cases   longi   lati
43613   1   -83.604452  41.704307
44140   1   -81.92148   41.48982
46052   1   -86.470531  40.051603
48009   22  -83.213883  42.544619
48017   6   -83.151815  42.535396
48021   7   -82.946167  42.463894
48025   19  -83.265758  42.523195
```

I want to get a map similar to this (if you can see it) in R. The outline should be zipcodes and the shading should be according to number of cases, darker as cases increase.

I'm very new to R. Tried a lot of code I found online but can't get what I want. Any help is appreciated. Can this be done in base SAS ?
Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kp3v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Definetly you can do it in R, I put together a reprex (reproducible example) for you. Key points:

1. You need to load into R a `.shp` file (or `.geojson`, `.gpkg`, etc.). That is an actual file with the outline of your map. For ZIPCODES I found a R package, `tigris`, that does that for you, if not you'll need to load it by yourself.
2. For handling mapping objects (load, transform, .etc), `sf` package is your best friend.
3. For plotting, in this example I used `cartography`, but you can use several different package, as `ggplot2` or `tmap`.

Last line is that, given your data (and if I didn't get the ZIPCODEs wrong), a map as the one you shown (choropleth map) maybe is not the best options. Have a look [here](http://riatelab.github.io/cartography/docs/articles/cartography.html) to see other alternatives.

```r
library(sf) #Overall handling of sf objects
library(cartography) #Plotting maps package

#1. Create your data
yourdata <- data.frame(ZCTA5CE10=c("43613", "44140", "46052",
                                "48009","48017", "48021","48025"),
                    Cases=c(1,1,1,22,6,7,19)
                    )

#2. Download a shapefile (shp,gpkg,geojson...)
library(tigris) #For downloading the zipcode map
options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)
geo <- st_as_sf(zctas(cb = TRUE, starts_with = yourdata$ZCTA5CE10))

#Overall shape of USA states
states <- st_as_sf(states(cb=TRUE))
#For plotting, all the maps should have the same crs
states=st_transform(states,st_crs(geo))

#3. Now Merge your data
yourdata.sf=merge(geo,yourdata)

#4. Plotting
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
ghostLayer(yourdata.sf)
plot(st_geometry(states), add=TRUE)
choroLayer(yourdata.sf,
           var="Cases",
           add=TRUE,
           border = NA,
           legend.pos = "right",
           legend.frame = TRUE)
layoutLayer(title = "Cases by ZIPCODE",
            theme = "blue.pal",
            scale = FALSE,
            sources = "Source; your question on SO",
            author = "by dieghernan, 2020"
            )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>